# In the context of a vector space, *should* the vectors have the same origin?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

In the context of a vector space, *should* the vectors have the same origin ?

My question is connected to:
[Is it true that "one does not add two vectors of different origin"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373692/is-it-true-that-one-does-not-add-two-vectors-of-different-origin?noredirect=1#comment9139274_4373692)

Comment: In the context of *vector space*, vectors don't even *have* origins. They are abstract entities that you can add and multiply by scalars. In *geometry*, you have *pairs of points* and you have vectors (from a vector space) associated to those pairs. So, again, the vectors themselves don't have origins, but you can go from vectors to pairs of points and back, if you want to calculate, say, a sum of two vectors. How you choose those points is a matter of practicality. Some geometry books will advise to bring the vectors to the same origin and draw a parallelogram, others will advise ...

Comment: ...bringing the origin of the second vector to the end of the first and drawing a triangle!  It can be proven that those *methods of adding vectors by going to the pairs of points and back* are equivalent and so you can pick whatever one your book advises.

Comment: @Stinking Bishop : thank you for your kind help.